# How to get the id from iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, youtube

I am tring to get the youtube id from the iframe. And using this link for regular expression given by this link [here](http://regex101.com/r/vY6eV7)

I am using this code but getting the array(0){} result. Here is the code:

`

```
    preg_match('/src="\/\/(?:https?:\/\/)?.*\/(.*?)\?rel=\d*"/',$urldd, $matches);

     var_dump($matches);
        echo $matches[0][0];`
```

I am poor in using preg_match so please can anyone help me to get the youtube id from iframe properly.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can also use `DOMDocument` to get that particular url, then use `parse_url()`. Sample Code:

```
$html = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0gugBiEkLwU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$iframe = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
$url = '';
foreach($iframe as $tag) {
    $url = $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
$output = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pieces = array_filter(explode('/', $output));
$id = end($pieces);

// Should output 0gugBiEkLwU
```

If you insist to use regex, you could do something like this:

```
$pattern = '#(?<=(?:v|i)=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=(?:v|i)\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=embed\/)[^"&\n]+|(?<=‌​(?:v|i)=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+#';
$html = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0gugBiEkLwU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);
$url = reset($matches);
$url = strtok($url, '?');
echo $url; // 0gugBiEkLwU
```

Comment: Thankyou... You made it so easy..Thanks again

Comment: @user3739733 you can also use preg_match if you insist

Comment: @user3739733 sure glad it helped, if it did, kindly click the green check thank you